# How universal link works in IOS?

Tags: xcode, ios9, deep-linking, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

We created universal link for our app following apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

And its working fine, when I tap on link, my app open successfully. But at status bar of my app I am getting two link.
1. At left top side, back to sms app, where I received link.
2. Other at right top side, my app appstore link.

If I tap on link 2, universal links no lpnger works.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by (Apple's) design. To re-enable Universal Linking behavior, either long-press on the URL in an app like Notes or Message, or once you are on the fallback page just scroll all the way up until an `Open` banner appears.

Answer (score 0):

Re-enable Universal Link will only work if you have added right Domains: applinks:www.example.com
in Associates Domains column.

If associate domains not starting with www. then please recheck the link you want to open must not have www. in front of it.